# How to calculate error compared to true value?

Tags: measurement-error, measurement, agreement-statistics

Suppose I have measured 25 subjects two times. The first measurement is a measurement tool and the second measurement is the true value. I would like to know how close the measurements of the tool are, when compared to the true value. Ideally, this value will  be put into a 95% confidence interval, to be able to say: 'The error of the measurement tool is between value x and y in 95% of the cases.'

Can I accomplish this by taking the difference between the two measurements in every subject and calculate the 95% confidence interval of these values?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "maximum error."  After all, you have only two measurements and (by definition) the error is their difference.  How would the concept of maximization apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to calculate the average difference and its confidence interval as you propose. Another option would be to use a measure such as the intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC) to quantify the agreement or consistency between the tool and your trusted measurements. Whereas the former gives you an unstandardized estimate of error, the latter would give you a standardized estimate of reliability.